# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

estoy tratando de capturar la Finalizacion de un Video de YouTube de un Iframe (La URL se carga dinamicamente despues de ejecutar otro evento). He averiguado y se que se debe de usar si o si la API de YouTube, la trate de implementar pero me sale el siguiente error.

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://mydomain.com').

Sinceramente no lo entiendo, e incluso paso los paramateros origin por URL como varias preguntas que he investigado similares. Alguna solucion

```
    var player_youtube;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
    player_youtube = new YT.Player('link_video_promocional', {
        playerVars: 
        { 
            'host' : 'https://www.youtube.com',
            'widget_referrer' : 'https://mydomain.com',
            'autoplay': 1,
            'origin': 'https://mydomain.com',
            'videoId' : idYoutube
        },
    });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.END) {
      console.log("Verificar Ciclo");
      verificarCicloDeVideos();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Tu API está correcto? Al parecer no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la **API** correcta de **Youtube**:

```
var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

Luego tu función, lo cual **nó probé**:

```
var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.END) {
     console.log("Verificar Ciclo");
     verificarCicloDeVideos();
}

      done = true;
    }
  }
```